# Producing the .i source file giving error

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor

I'm following a [tutorial](https://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/cpp/gcc_make.html) on how the various processes of the compiling work and in order to learn the process I'm producing the executable "by hand" by creating the `.i` file first. In order to do so I'm doing the command:

```
cpp a.cpp > a.i
```

**a.cpp:**

```
#include<iostream>

int main() {
    return 0;
}
```

But an error occurs:

```
a.cpp:1:9: fatal error: 'iostream' file not found
#include<iostream>
        ^~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
```

even though the file **a.i** still gets created with the content:

```
# 1 "a.cpp"
# 1 "<built-in>" 1
# 1 "<built-in>" 3
# 383 "<built-in>" 3
# 1 "<command line>" 1
# 1 "<built-in>" 2
# 1 "a.cpp" 2


int main() {
  return 0;
}
```

Am I supposed to specify the location of `iostream` library in order to produce the `.i` file? The tutorial doesn't mention it anywhere and I wonder why is it needed at this point.

Comment: Side note: The tutorial brings up Cygwin a lot. Unless you need Cygwin's POSIX compatibility layer, consider [using MSYS2 instead](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30071634/4581301). If you do need POSIX, a Linux container or VM is usually more effective than Cygwin.

Answer (score 3):

In absence of specification, cpp (the C PreProcessor) is assuming the language you're using is C.

Try passing the `-x` argument to tell it your language is C++.

```
cpp -xc++ a.cpp > a.i
```

Comment: Side note: cpp in this case stands for C PreProcessor, not C Plus Plus.

Comment: now it gives me +20 erros at `/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/AvailabilityInternal.h`like `#endif /* #if defined(__has_builtin) */`

Comment: Always deal with the first error first, but that sounds like material for a different question.